# php form validation message appearing twice

Tags: php, forms, contacts

I have a php contact form on my website and the successful validation message is appearing twice. I am not sure what part of the code to show, html, css, or php. So let me know what you want to see and I can share it below.

The url is http://uspeqtest.000webhostapp.com/contact-us.html if anyone wants to see the form. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: It will be better you post your script here; they can't be seen.

Comment: What script needs to be seen? The php?

Comment: Any idea in which file I can look for that and delete one of the requests?

Comment: @nyedidikeke I am not sure which script you are talking about. Is it the formvalidation.php or formconfig.php?

I am not sure which fie controls the form validation so it makes it tough for me to post the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are including your JS file 2 times in your HTML document.

```
line 29 : <script src="cfgen-form-3/js/form.js"></script>
```

And

```
line 66 : <script src="cfgen-form-3/js/form.js"></script>
```

Comment: This got it fixed! Thanks so much Tom Ah!

Answer (score 1):

Your script creates two AJAX requests. I guess you should use more frequently the browser's tools, like FireBug in Firefox, or Inspect in Chrome to check the requests you are creating.

See this [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DKbuw.jpg) for more info.

And you should look at your AJAX code, obviously, and/or post it here.